# Equal top row/item height in Flexbox columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I've got a column component which sits inside a flex wrapper.  Multiple column components can exist next to each other, and each column contains multiple flex items.

I need the top item in each column to be equal height, simulating a row.  I don't really want to use a fixed height as it will break if the user adjusts their browser font size or if the content moves to a CMS and changes in length.  Is there a way to do this in Flexbox?  If not, is there a way to do it using CSS Grid or similar?

eg:

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="topRow">
      Some content
    </div>
    <p>Needs to align</p>
    <p>Something</p>
    <p>Something</p>
    <p>Something</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="topRow">
      Some content which is a bit longer
    </div>
    <p>Needs to align</p>
    <p>Something</p>
    <p>Something</p>
    <p>Something</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="topRow">
      Some content
    </div>
    <p>Needs to align</p>
    <p>Something</p>
    <p>Something</p>
    <p>Something</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper { 
  display: flex;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.column {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image: Code output]

---

**UPDATE: Here's a working solution using Flexbox:**

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="header">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae mauris arcu. Donec et lorem ac nulla scelerisque egestas.
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="infoRows">
        <p>Needs to align</p>
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="header">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae mauris arcu. Donec et lorem ac nulla scelerisque egestas.
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="infoRows">
        <p>Needs to align</p>
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    <div class="header">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae mauris arcu. Donec et lorem ac nulla scelerisque egestas.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae mauris arcu. Donec et lorem ac nulla scelerisque egestas.
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="infoRows">
        <p>Needs to align</p>
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    <div class="header">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae mauris arcu. Donec et lorem ac nulla scelerisque egestas.
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="infoRows">
        <p>Needs to align</p>
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  @media (max-width: 900px) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
.column {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
.info {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: end;
}
.infoRows {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
.infoRows p {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Output:
[image: Solution output]

Comment: Please have a  look here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ ..

Comment: Unless I'm missing it, that article doesn't have a solution to the issue I'm describing.

Comment: What do you want to happen if wrap occurs?

Comment: The columns will wrap onto individual lines in smaller viewports, the top “row” needs to stay the same height across all columns based on the max height of the tallest content

Comment: Why don't you insert data in rows instead of columns is there any restriction with that approach?

Comment: I need the columns to be stacked vertically on small viewports (unless I’m misunderstanding your comment?)

Comment: You can use table as it is impossible to match the height of the elements which are not under the same div/container.

Comment: With table you can achieve that

Comment: Or you can use JS to calculate and apply height to elements that are in the same row.

Comment: Yeah, JS isn't the right choice here although I don't doubt it would work.  Tables are low on my list of options as it creates too many restrictions with styling and layout.

Comment: Provide design layout (ex. figma) we will create for you with table.

Comment: Show me a table layout where I can use a media query to break the row-based layout into stacked columns I'll refactor my solution :)

Comment: Please check I have added an answer to the scenario you mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned in the comments, I hope this approach will help you.

```css
table {
    width:100%;
    padding:0px 50px;
}
.column1 {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
}
.column2 {
    background:blue;
    height:50px;
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
    th,tr {
        width:100%;
        display: block;
        margin:10px 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th class="column1">1</th>
        <th class="column2">1</th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <th class="column1">2<br>2<br>2</th>
        <th class="column2">2</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```